# How to get an updated cell value in google sheets

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to send an email to myself if my script in python does not run anymore.

I have implemented in python an uptime function. Cell E5 gets updated with the new uptime every 15 seconds. If the uptime does not change my script does not run anymore and i want to get notified via email. For this reason i compare the cell value after 5 minutes.

But uptime_zahl and uptime_new_zahl are always equal the value when i start my apps script function.

How can I get the updated cell value??

```
function uptimeCheck() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt1');
var uptime_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue().toString();
var uptime_zahl = Number(uptime_string.replace(',', "."));
Utilities.sleep(300000);//wait for 5 minutes

var uptime_new_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue().toString();
var uptime_new_zahl = Number(uptime_new_string.replace(',', "."));  
  if (uptime_zahl == uptime_new_zahl)
  {
    var emailAddress = 'XXX';
    var subject = 'The bot does not run';
    var message = 'old time: '+uptime_zahl+'new time: '+uptime_new_zahl;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,message);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can store `uptime_zahl` in [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) and run your automatically script on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (e.g. every 5 minutes).

The following sample

- sets during the first run the script property 'uptime_zahl' to the actual value in "E5" and the `sent` status to `0`
- compares the current value in "E5" against the one stored during the last script run
- sends an email if the value is still the same and an email has not been sent yet
- sets the script property to the current value and `sent` to `1`, if an email for the current value has been sent already

```
function uptimeCheck() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt1');
var uptime_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue().toString();
var uptime_new_zahl = Number(uptime_string.replace(',', "."));

if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ // first time you run the script
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('uptime_zahl',uptime_new_zahl);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('sent',0);
}
var sent=parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('sent'));  
var uptime_zahl = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('uptime_zahl');
if (uptime_zahl == uptime_new_zahl&&sent==0)
  {
    Logger.log('still the same, email sent: '+uptime_zahl);
    var emailAddress = 'XXX';
    var subject = 'The bot does not run';
    var message = 'old time: '+uptime_zahl+'new time: '+uptime_new_zahl;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,message);
    sent=1;
  }else if(uptime_zahl != uptime_new_zahl){
    sent=0;
    Logger.log('value changed');
  }else{
    Logger.log('value did not change, but email has been sent already');
  }               
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('uptime_zahl',uptime_new_zahl);  
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('sent',sent);  
}
```

> To set up a time-driven trigger:

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) That works. But if the uptime does not change anymore i get an email every five minutes. Is it possible to get just one email?

Comment: I see, can you confirm what your desired workflow is? If there value A did not change for more than 5 minutes, you want to get one email. If at a later time point value A changes to value B, but then again does not change for 5 minutes - would you like to receive an email again?

Comment: Yes, that describes it!

Comment: Thanks:) Can you please explain or send a source where i can find what PropertiesService?
Do you know a good source to get an introductions to google-apps script and JS?

Comment: The link in my answer will refer you to the official Google Apps Script documentation of the method. General introduction to GAS and JS: https://developers.google.com/apps-script, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript